# Instagram API data do not match Instgram Insights data

Tags: instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to get IG insights data by using graph API, but the API is returning different data than it's showing in Instagram Insights. The results as below. I think it's maybe the timezone issue, but how can I get the same results by using API. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[Instagram insights result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qsYo.jpg)

[Graph API result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBaku.png)

Comment: What's the query that you've executed?

Comment: I’m executed below query: GET graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/insights
    ?metric=reach&period=Day&since={}&until={}

Comment: since you're asking for the reach metric, the response is correct, you can also try other metrics like user-id/insights?metric= audience_city&period=lifetime, more metrics can be found here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/insights

Comment: But how can I get the same daliy result with Instagram insights?

Comment: Was there any update on this? Seeing the same issue where we get a higher result from graph api than insights